# Why does my control ID not work when I add an Eval statement to my Datatextfield?

Tags: c#, telerik, eval, rad-controls

code:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="CboLists"
DataTextField="<%# Eval("Attributes['listname']") %>" DataValueField="Id">
//rest of the combobox, includes an itemtemplate;
```

It works just fine without `DataTextField="<%# Eval("Attributes['listname']") %>"`, but once I add this, CboLists turns red and it says "The name CboLists does not exist in the current context".

The combobox is populated on page load with a list of type `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity`. I want to show a specific attribute of the selected entity if the combobox is not shown, but I cannot figure out how to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Eval is correct you need to using right combination of single and double quotes.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="CboLists"
DataTextField='<%# Eval(Attributes["listname"]) %>' DataValueField="Id">
```

Comment: When I use that, it states "cannot access internal class Attributes Here". Attributes is a member of the DataItem that's used in the combobox.

Comment: You probably need to redesign the datasource, one id should have on value for DataTextField

Comment: But there is only 1 Id. I'm using the Dynamics CRM 2013 SDK with late bound entities. The Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity class has a property called "Attributes" which is basically a dictionary and can be accessed through entity.Attributes["fieldname"]. It contains a key-valuepair list of all fields of the Entity.

Comment: If entity.Attributes["fieldname"] is key-value pair then what you want to make a text of DataTextField?. You can assign as datasource, ddl.DataSource = entity.Attributes["fieldname"]; and <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="CboLists"
DataTextField="Key" DataValueField="Value">

Comment: Because I have an itemtemplate which needs to access different fields of that dictionary. So I need to use the entity class as the datasource and use a few <%# Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Attributes['listname']" %> in my Itemtemplate, which gets the attribute with name "listname" from the Attributes property of my Entity. however, I want to show the listname in the combobox, where it now just shows Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity.

Comment: Check if OnDataBound of dropdownlist can help you, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.ondatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it fixed the problem I have with my control ID, but I'm going to ask another question for the followup I have. I'd be surprised if this can't be solved by 1 or 2 lines of code.